# CSS font-size: Set it for * as multiple of rem and body font-size is multiplied twice

Tags: html, css, font-size

See the console output of the code snippet below. I use a multiplier of 0.5 in the example because it makes the multiplication straightforward and illustrates that it can double-shrink the font-size as well as double-increase it.

I set font-size to 0.5rem using the `*` universal selector. No other settings. The documentElement font-size is 8px, as I would expect when the default for 1rem at 16px (8 = 16 x 0.5). But the body font-size is 4px, which is 16 x 0.5 x 0.5. Why does this happen?

I realize that the `*` selector is not always good practice, and if I use the `html` selector both values are correctly set to 8px here; but then in my actual page the font-size does not inherit to all elements. I'm open to suggestions on the best practice here.

I have tested this in Chrome and Firefox on Windows with the same results.

EDIT: I just discovered that using the combined `html *` selector I can achieve my desired result: global setting without the double multiplier.

```js
console.log("doc:  " + getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
console.log("body: " + getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize);
```

```css
* { font-size: 0.5rem; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-rem-in-css-rem-unit-font-size-padding-height-and-more/):

> rem stands for root em, which is a measurement unit that refers to the font-size of the root element of a document. It is a relative unit, which means all values that use it change when the root's font-size changes. The root element in this case refers to the html element.

If you add more element, you will find that `rem` and `em` are different.

When use `rem`, font-size will change basic on `html`.

```js
console.log("doc:  " + getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
console.log("body: " + getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize);
console.log("div: " + getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div')).fontSize);
console.log("p: " + getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('p')).fontSize);
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

When use `em`, font-size basic on parent element

```js
console.log("doc:  " + getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
console.log("body: " + getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize);
console.log("div: " + getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div')).fontSize);
console.log("p: " + getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('p')).fontSize);
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

And `html{font-size:0.5rem}` is also different from `*{font-size:0.5rem}`.

When use `*`, it changes all elements. So:

1. the default `<html>` font-size is 16px.
2. `<html>` is `0.5rem` = 8px (half of `html` default, now `<html>` is 8px)
3. `<body>` also become `0.5rem` = 4px (now `<html>` is 8px, 8px * 0.5 = 4px)
4. other element like `<div>`, `<p>` are `0.5rem` = 4px (`<html>` is 8px, 8px * 0.5 = 4px).

When use `html`, it only change `<html>`'s font-size, so `<html>` is `0.5rem` = 8px, and all other elements are same font-size(8px) as `<html>`

Comment: It's not only rem units. I just now tried this with em units and got the same result. Your answer almost makes sense to me, but I need more detail as to why the multiplication happens twice. My understanding of the `*` selector is that it applies to every element. So why wouldn't it apply the same value everywhere instead of cascading the multiplier just once from `html` to `body`, and then all elements below inherit 4px from `body`? Why would `*{font-size:0.5rem}` produce a different result from `html{font-size:0.5rem}`?

Comment: @SidewaysS You are right `*`  is that it applies to every element but , in you case (parent element = root element )`rem` & `em` are working based on root & parent  element default size. because of that this type of answer you get. for more clarification check that difference between `rem` and `em`.

Comment: @I_am_prince - so then any time I use `rem` or `em` units in other rules it will be based on the documentElement's version of the unit, at 8px, because `*` sets that first. `rem` and `em` are thus reset at the root. Then when `*` applies the font-size to all the other elements it's using the newly calculated units. That's what almost made sense to me about this answer originally, but you've clarified a bit with the parent vs root distinction. I just created this codepen to prove it to myself: https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/mdvRXxQ.  Thanks.

Comment: @Shuo - thanks for the expanded answer and snippets.  It's all starting to make sense now. I just discovered that what I really need is the combined `html *` selector in order to apply a global font-size without the double-multiplication.