# Understanding the CSS unit "rem"

Tags: css

I was learning CSS where I got to a point in which I have to arrange text inside a div and I have to set the font-size to 0.85rem. What is the difference between using font-size normally and using `rem` with the value?

Comment: Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77435301/18229259).

Comment: Hello LearnProgramming_0985, you should read or watch one of the numerous tutorials that are available on the web. Here, questions are on these topics: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

Comment: The value of a rem unit can be set outside the CSS - the user can set it in the browser for example for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score -1):

In CSS, the rem ("root" em) unit is relative to the document's root element.

While the em unit is only relative to the immediate parent of the targeted element.

Here are some examples of common font sizes expressed in rem units:

```
10px = 0.625rem  
12px = 0.75rem  
14px = 0.875rem  
16px = 1rem (base)  
18px = 1.125rem  
20px = 1.25rem  
24px = 1.5rem  
30px = 1.875rem  
32px = 2rem
```

Comment: This is a slight misunderstanding. The amounts shown assume rem has been set at 16px. What happens when that is changed? A user can set rem to be what they want in the browser settings and this should not be overridden because it is an accessibility issue.

Comment: @AHaworth By default, most browsers use a font size value of 16px (for the root of the HTML document). I have provided these values as a (common) example to illustrate the unit in rem vs em vs px.

Comment: You are correct that by default many browsers do that, but the point is that the user can change it so your table needs more clarification - to emphasise that this is default in many situations but cannot be relied on (and also, for accessibility, should not be tampered with).